# Get Symbol from CatchDeclaration

Tags: c#, roslyn, .net-4.6

How do I get the symbol info of the instance in a CatchDeclaration? Basically I want to get the symbol so that I can compare it later to see that a method was called on that symbol.

Basically I have this: `catch (Exception ex) {}` and I want the SymbolInfo for "ex".

I get the catch declaration with:

```
var catchDeclaration = catchClause.DescendantNodes().OfType<CatchDeclarationSyntax>().FirstOrDefault();
```

But I seem to only be able to get the SyntaxToken from the declaration (`catchDeclaration.Identifier`) which cannot be used to get a symbol from the semantic model since that only takes a SyntaxNode.

Comment: You are working with the syntax model, which will only give you syntax information with no semantics. You need to use the semantic model to get that information: https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/2014/10/30/learn-roslyn-now-part-7-introducing-the-semantic-model/

Comment: @David But my question is exactly how to get the symbol from the semantic model if I have the catchDeclaration. Or is it already too late at that point in time and I have to use the semantic model earlier? (but I don't see how I'd get the catch declaration or similar through the semantic model then?). Basically `model.GetSymbolInfo(catchDeclaration.Identifier)` doesn't work because the identifier is a token not a node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(theCatchDeclarationItself)`. The method to call is [here](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/CSharpExtensions.cs,e07bdc198e03e603) and is an extension method, so make sure you've got using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis at the top of your file.

In general, `GetSymbolInfo` is used when you're binding a variable that points somewhere else. `GetDeclaredSymbol` is used for "get me the symbol being defined here".