# Roslyn: Get Symbol from catch declaration having no variable name

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I have a `CatchDeclarationSyntax` instance and I want to get the symbol for the type that is catched in the statement.

If the catch declaration contains a variable name for the type being catched, I can do it as described in this article here:
[Get Symbol from CatchDeclaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33275697/get-symbol-from-catchdeclaration)

Example:

```
...
catch(NullReferenceException exception)
{
    ...
}
```

Getting the symbol for the `NullReferenceException` type:

```
ILocalSymbol catchDeclarationSymbol = semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(catchDeclarationSyntax);
ITypeSymbol exceptionType = catchDeclarationSymbol.Type;
```

This works fine.

But if the catch declaration *doesn't* contain a variable name for the type being catched, I have problems.

Example:

```
...
catch(NullReferenceException)
{
    ...
}
```

Getting the symbol for type `NullReferenceException` *doesn't* work this way:

```
ILocalSymbol catchDeclarationSymbol = semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(catchDeclarationSyntax);
// catchDeclarationSymbol is now null
```

Does anybody have an idea how to get the symbol for the `NullReferenceException` type in this case?

Comment: Does `catchDeclarationSyntax.Type` work?

Comment: Have you tried `SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But if the catch declaration *doesn't* contain a variable name for the type being catched, I have problems.

That's because you can't use `GetDeclaredSymbol` when there is no symbol being declared. `catch(NullReferenceException exception)` declares the `exception` symbol, but `catch(NullReferenceException)` does not.

Instead, you can access the syntax node for the type and then get the type symbol for that:

```
ITypeSymbol exceptionType = model.GetTypeInfo(catchDeclarationSyntax.Type).Type;
```